# How to detect that my pc or server is in vpn or not with php

Tags: php, networking, vpn

I have a php application which has been set in windows scheduler to run in some interval. It tries to communicate with some different servers, and now to communicate with this servers a proxy ip is being used as part of php curl code. Now some time I have to enter into some vpn network. And when I am in vpn network then I have to detect that I am in a vpn network so that proxy (which I am using in my code) will be changed to some another one. So the challenge is to detect that my pc or server is in vpn through php or with windows command is also acceptable.

Comment: Do you work for netflix ?

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: Aside from checking routing table in windows, or fetching data from ifconfig.co and checking it against a list of known proxies/VPN's I cannot think of anything.

Comment: @MaazRehman no, I am not

Answer (score 0):

You may compare the IP address against a database of addresses known to belong to VPN networks.

This is a tough work.